# NavDeepLinkBuilder on Android 12 real mobile cause crash

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-deep-link

NavDeepLinkBuilder succeed At Android 9,10 but fail at Android 12 real mobile.Why?
I would like to navigate from Activity to fragment so use NavDeepLinkBuilder because
other method like findNavController or beginTransaction all failed.

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
                    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
                    .setDestination(R.id.selectLocationFragment)
                    .createPendingIntent().send()
```

build.gradle

```
 // Navigation
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 
// Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'